# tvml "an error occured loading this content" TVML Programming Guide

Tags: tvml

Link to TVML Program Guide: [TVML program guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/TVMLKitJS/Conceptual/TVMLProgrammingGuide/PlayingVideo.html)

It loads the single video just fine - but when i try to load mulitaple videos it errors out. something about how this video wasnt found on the server.

```
http://localhost:9001/http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4, NSURL=http://localhost:9001/http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4, NSLocalizedDescription=The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

ive tried downloading and putting the big_buck_bunny.mp4 file in my server files but still no luck. am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

if you have an external video source, you won't need the `http://localhost:9001/` part, just `http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4` would be enough.

most likely you forgot to remove the `baseURL` form `var videourl = baseURL + extension;`